# Return Value of oAuth.RequestToken(code) is null Always in InstaSharp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, instagram-api, instasharp

I am using InstaSharp for my ASp.Net MVC application. My problem is every time following code returns null. ( RequestToken(code) always return a OAuthResponse Instance with AccessToken = null , User = null)

```
 OAuthResponse oAuthResponse = await oAuth.RequestToken(code);
```

So i can t get user id from oAuthResponse. here is my code.

```
public async Task<IList<Media>> GetInstagramMediaList(string clientId, string clientSecret, string returnUrl, string code)
        {
            List<Media> mediaResponseList = new List<Media>();
            InstagramConfig instagramConfig = new InstagramConfig(clientId, clientSecret, returnUrl, string.Empty);
            OAuth oAuth = new OAuth(instagramConfig);
            OAuthResponse oAuthResponse = await oAuth.RequestToken(code);

            Users users = new Users(instagramConfig, oAuthResponse);
            MediasResponse instaResponse = await users.Recent(oAuthResponse.User.Id.ToString());
            mediaResponseList.AddRange(instaResponse.Data);

            while (instaResponse.Pagination.NextMaxId != null)
            {
                instaResponse = await users.RecentSelf(maxId: instaResponse.Pagination.NextMaxId, minId: instaResponse.Pagination.NextMinId, count: null, maxTimestamp: null, minTimestamp: null);
                mediaResponseList.AddRange(instaResponse.Data);
            }

            return new List<Media>(mediaResponseList);
        }
```

if any one can give a solution for this it will be a great help to me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instasharp have updated the code.  Answer is here : [Insasharp](https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp/issues/115)